# I have a new pine floor finished with 2 coats poly. What should I use to fill in some countersunk nail holes before 3rd coat of poly?

Tags: filler

I have a new pine floor with 2 coats oil based poly (no stain).  I want to fill in numerous countersunk nail holes that were left unfilled.  I will be putting down a 3rd coat of poly after that.  Would Elmers Wood Filler work, or is there a better solution? I want to make sure whatever I use will stay put.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExhange. You want a time machine ^_^ (Filler goes on the bare wood, or wood that has been lightly 'sealed', not over a layer of varnish. )

Comment: I've never had to do anything like this so I don't really want to post this as an "answer", but the best thing I can think of would be a shellac-based pore filler stick.  Shellac is a "universal binder", and can adhere to almost any kind of finish.  Wax-based sticks definitely won't stick to a cured finish, but with the shellac you might have a chance.  Basically you melt a bit off the stick with a small iron (just bigger than a soldering iron), smear the melted goop into your hole, then level it out with a clean iron.

Comment: Thanks ror replies -  if I could get a hold of H.G. Wells, I'd be filling 2 poly's ago!  I've got a conundrum for sure, appreciate the shellac filler stick suggestion and will check into it.